# MIME::Entity headers encoding correct?

Tags: perl, email, encoding, header, mime

I use MIME::Entity module in Perl to create a MIME message. Some of the headers seem to be encoded OK, while other seem to have issues with folding.

Code:

```
use strict;
use Encode;
use MIME::Entity;

my %build_params = (
    'Charset'    => 'UTF-8',
    'From'       => encode('MIME-Header', 'Fantasy Email <vujerldujhgurtelhwgutrwhgunwlhvulhgvnuwlhvuwlnhvgnulwh@gmail.com>'),
    'Subject'    => encode('MIME-Header', "A very long subject that will span on multiple lines in the headers, with a leading sp\
ace at the beginning of each new line."),
    'Type'       => 'multipart/alternative',
);


my $top = MIME::Entity->build(%build_params);

$top->print_header();
```

Output:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----------=_1312196104-11708-0";
 charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MIME-tools 5.427 (Entity 5.427)
Subject: A very long subject that will span on multiple lines in the
 headers,  with a leading space at the beginning of each new line.
From: Fantasy Email
 <vujerldujhgurtelhwgutrwhgunwlhvulhgvnuwlhvuwlnhvgnulwh@gmail .com>
```

The `Subject` seems to be correctly split into multiple lines. The `From` doesn't, leaving a space before the `com`, but the newline is gone.

Is this standard behavior or have I found a bug in MIME::Entity?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Mostly the space before `.com`. Also, if you copied *exactly* what it produced, seems to be added a new space after `headers,`.

Comment: Hum, you're right about the double space after the comma. This one is clearly a bug.

Comment: Note also that the added space *may* be at the same position in both headers, so it may be a bug in the spliting expression on `MIME::Entity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode::MIME::Header (called as `encode('MIME-Header', ...)`) does some line splitting (called folding in the [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html)).

Unfortunately, MIME::Entity does some line splitting too, probably in a different way. It also gets rid of the newline generated by Encode::MIME::Header. It leaves the spaces though.

I would be happy to leave MIME::Entity deal with the encoding of my headers, but it looks like it just does the line splitting part. So I guess I still have to encode them myself.

As a workaround, I removed the line splitting markers from my encoded headers with

```
 my $encoded_from = encode('MIME-Header', 'Fantasy Email <vujerldujhgurtelhwgutrwhgunwlhvulhgvnuwlhvuwlnhvgnulwh@gmail.com>');
 $encoded_from =~ s/\r?\n\s//g;
```

(And same thing for the subject.)

Now the output looks like this:

```
Subject: A very long subject that will span on multiple lines in the
 headers, with a leading space at the beginning of each new line.
From: Fantasy Email
 <vujerldujhgurtelhwgutrwhgunwlhvulhgvnuwlhvuwlnhvgnulwh@gmail.com>
```

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution, like Encode::MIME::Header featuring a MIME::Entity compatibility mode or something like that.